# receiving "Cache not found for input keys: cache-playwright-linux-1.20.0" on github actions ubuntu-latest

Tags: ubuntu, github, caching, github-actions, playwright

I follow the example provided in
https://playwrightsolutions.com/playwright-github-action-to-cache-the/

in my yml file i have the following code

```
jobs:
test:
timeout-minutes: 60
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  with:
    node-version: '16.x
```

then i editted only the version here to match the current one

```
- name: Cache playwright binaries
  uses: actions/cache@v2
  id: playwright-cache
  with:
    path: |
      ~/.cache/ms-playwright
    key: cache-playwright-linux-1.20.0
```

after that i run

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: npm ci
- name: Install Playwright
  if: steps.playwright-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  run: npx playwright install --with-deps
- name: Run Playwright tests
  run: npm run test
```

i receive "Cache not found for input keys: cache-playwright-linux-1.20.0"

Comment: Caching browser's is usually not recommend, since downloading the browsers only takes a few seconds < 5 and restoring it takes usually longer. Also maintaining the correct cache key across versions is not "easy" since as you can see the key is hardcoded.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve your cache key by using the os and package-lock.json file. The latter part of the key probably changes more than preferred, but works for many builds.

```yaml
- uses: actions/cache@v2
  id: playwright-cache
  with:
    path: |
      ~/.cache/ms-playwright
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-playwright-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
- run: npm ci
- run: npx playwright install --with-deps
  if: steps.playwright-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
- run: npx playwright install-deps
  if: steps.playwright-cache.outputs.cache-hit == 'true'
```

https://justin.poehnelt.com/posts/caching-playwright-in-github-actions/

Answer (score 1):

This strategy worked for me (with chromium dependency):

```yaml
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Get installed Playwright version
        id: playwright-version
        run: echo "version=$(npm ls @playwright/test | grep @playwright | sed 's/.*@//')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Cache Playwright
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: playwright-cache
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/ms-playwright
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-playwright-${{ steps.playwright-version.outputs.version }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-playwright-

      - name: Install Playwright and dependencies
        run: npx playwright install --with-deps chromium
        if: steps.playwright-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'

      - name: Install only Playwright dependencies
        run: npx playwright install-deps chromium
        if: steps.playwright-cache.outputs.cache-hit == 'true'
```

Result:
[image].

[image].
To find more see GitHub discussion https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/7249